# Comment multiple xml files with sed

Tags: xml, sed

I want to comment multiple xml lines with sed command.The lines are from a kubernetes container who use tomcat.There are other lines who starts with Valve. I have this:

```
<!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

and I want to comment this part:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

so the final output will be:

```
    <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
<!--         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
 -->
```

I tried something like this:

```
sed -r '/^\s*<Valve className\s*=\s*"org\.apache\.catalina\.valves\.AccessLogValve"\s**$/{h;z;N;s:^\n::;H;/^\s*prefix\s*=\s*"localhost\_\access\_\log"\s*\/>\s*$/{g;s/.*/<!--\n&\n-->/}}'
```

but it doesn't work.How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: IMHO, experts always advise to parse XML files with xml aware tools. Are you allowed to use Python's modules OR `xmlstarlet` like tools? If yes then you can add those tags in your question and experts could jump in. If you are not allowed for those techs(eg: you aren't allowed to install software) then confirm here, so that we could try to help within OOTB tools eg: `sed` etc.

Comment: No I can't use xmlstarlet. I try to execute that sed in a dockerfile to comment those lines from tomcat contaier, to avoid the creation of that log file in the container, so I must do it with sed

Comment: is `xmllint` an option, uses to be an OOTB tool from libxml2 packages.

Comment: I need just a sed in the project I'm working on

Comment: @EugenGîrlescu, ok sure. could you please do post samples of input and expected output more clearly in your question(post lines samples which will get commented along with which are left over by rule), thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I edited my question and I added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would comment relevant lines out whether the element is in a single line or multiple ones

```
sed -r -i.bak '/<Valve className=.*AccessLogValve/ s/.*/<!--&/; s/(prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix="\.txt"|pattern="%h .+ %s %b") *\/>/& -->/' server.xml
```

works on both forms

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" 
            prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" 
            pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" /> 

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" 
                pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"
                prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/ +<Valve className="org\.apache\.catalina\.valves\.AccessLogValve"[^>]*>/<!-- &\n-->/' input_file
<!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
<!--     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
-->
```